# Ansible: pinging windows machine using basic authentication

Tags: ansible

I have configured WinRM at Windows Server 2012 machine using the script suggested by Ansible team: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

At Ansible control machine (Linux box), the configuration looks like this:

```
ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: PASS
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Trying to ping Windows machine I still get:

```
10.2.75.142 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

User credentials are working credentials of local Windows user, belonging to Administrator group. Am I still missing some config on either side?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem. Through Ansible I was getting:

```
the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

but when executing command from windows machine using winrs it was fine. For example:

```
winrs -r:https://myserver.com -u:Administrator -p:PASS ipconfig
```

was going through.

Unfortunately didn't find any solution to have Ansible running with basic authentication. **Workaround** was to use **NTLM authentication**. Just added

```
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
```

to control machine configuration and it works fine ever since.